# Triplet Loss for face recognition is not working on test dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, siamese-network

I have created a face recognition model by using Triplet Loss on the Siamese network.

1. The model overfits while training with a small dataset. (it seems the model is working fine)
2. The loss is decreasing perfectly.

The problem is when I use this model on test data it is not working fine. Maybe the problem is with the training dataset. The overall size of my training data is 11,000, in which only 2000 - 2500 are the unique images. A single data contain (anchor, positive, negative) image.

Is there something I can do to increase the performance of the model? (Please help me out)

The Loss class

```
class TripletLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, margin):
        super(TripletLoss, self).__init__()
        self.margin = margin
        self.device = device

    def forward(self, anchor, positive, negative):
        # anchor, positive, negative are the activation values of last hidden 
        # layer of the siamese network. layer of size 200.
        
        # anchor, positive, negative shape -> (batch_size, 200)

        loss = torch.clamp(torch.sum(torch.square(anchor - positive), dim=1)
                           - torch.sum(torch.square(anchor - negative), dim=1)
                           + self.margin, min=0)
        return torch.mean(loss)

    def distance(self, output1, output2):
        diff = F.pairwise_distance(output1, output2)
        return diff
```

Comment: Well, if the model overfits on the training set it is no surprise that it isn't doing great on the test set - if the sets are indeed distinct.

Comment: I know that if the model overfits on training data then it won't perform well on test data. Firstly, I decided to train the model on small data ( a set of 40 examples ) to see it is overfitting or not, then I trained it on 11000 datasets. That's I wanted to say.

Comment: You can increase the batch size and use the learning rate scheduler, batch normalization, or regularization.